# LaTeX3 expansion in a coffin box

Tags: expansion, latex3

I am stranded with my attempts to set up a coffin box, which expands some variables, which are typeset in it.

---

**EDIT**

Background info: I am trying to write a package, which will allow the user to write, say for example, a minutes or a memo file.  Corporate design rules require, that the name of the author as well as other information (date, organisation, things like that) are printed in a box, usually located top right on the page.  On the left hand side, there is the logo.

In case, the document is not intended for print, you're required to have the logo, the author box and the right hand side margin filled with light grey color.  If printed on paper, you have two options.  Preferable you use preprinted paper, where the logo and grey box is already present, so logo and grey margin box must not be included in your document (but the author box of course must!).  If this preprinted paper is not at hand, you should correct the position of the logo, grey margin box and the authors info box slightly inwards, due to the usual limitations of the (laser-, ink jet, ...) printers, which are not capable to print up to the borders of the given paper.

The concept of predefined/prefilled coffin boxes seemed to be the tool of choice for me.

---

I defined a local variable `l__author_tl`.  To make the point clear, the variable is initialised with a starting value.  I also defined a document command, to manipulate the value of the variable.

Next I defined a coffin `l__author_coffin` which prints the variable `l__author_tl`.  This works well, so far, but the variable is not expanded, as you can see demonstrated in my MWE.

```latex
\documentclass{arcticle}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
%% Defining the internal, local author variable
\tl_new:N \l__author_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l__author_tl {first\ value}
%% How to manipulate the variable
\NewDocumentCommand{\myauthor} {m}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__author_tl {#1}
  }
%% Just for debugging: print out the actual value of the variable
\NewDocumentCommand {\printauthor} {}
  {
    \l__author_tl
  }
%% Create a new coffin box and define its content.
\coffin_new:N \l__author_coffin
\hcoffin_set:Nn \l__author_coffin
  {
    \sffamily\footnotesize
    \tl_use:N \l__author_tl\ 
    \today 
  }
%% This command will print out the coffin box
\NewDocumentCommand {\mybox} {}
  {
    \fbox{%
      \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l__author_coffin {l}{t}{0pt}{0pt}%
    }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
%% Print the box, as is
\mybox
%% Redefine the authors name
\myauthor{new value}
%% Just to be sure, the value of \l__author_tl was changed.
\printauthor
%% Print the box again
\mybox
\end{document}
```

As you can see from the output below, the coffin works, but it won't expand the variable content.

[image: Output of the coffin, which does not expand]

(I defined the variable to be a local internal variable.  I experimented with a global variable as well.  Same results!)

I am new to LaTeX3 and have difficulties in understanding when what expands.  I also tried to add `\tl_use:N \l__author_tl` in the coffin, getting the same unexpanded result.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Boxes are not token lists: once something is typeset, it's no longer got any link to any variables in the input. Could you explain your use case a little more?

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you again for your ongoing support.  I will edit my question.

Comment: a coffin is a typeset box you can not change the text in it. It is a fancy version of `\newsavebox\mybox \sbox\mybox{...}` which will show the same behaviour of expanding and typesetting all text at the point the box is saved. If you want the text to change you must reset the coffin

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle, than I should write some `\CreateCoffin` and `\UseCoffin` commands.

Comment: [Creating and using coffins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sv_GcxkmW4Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the coffin when doing `\myauthor`, because once a coffin is set, its contents is fixed because already typeset.

```
%% This command will print out the coffin box
\NewDocumentCommand {\mybox} {}
  {
    \hcoffin_set:Nn \l__author_coffin
      {
        \sffamily\footnotesize
        \tl_use:N \l__author_tl\ 
        \today 
      }
    \fbox{%
      \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l__author_coffin {l}{t}{0pt}{0pt}%
    }
  }
```